# jQuery image animate

Tags: jquery

I have a row of images that animate trought jQuery (zoom effect) when mouseover, and then gets back to their original size then mouseout.

The problem is that when an image gets zoomed, it increases its size and push the other images of the table row to the sides.

Its there a way to prevent this? Even if an image gets above another.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.menu").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:300,width:300,opacity:1.0},"fast");
  });
  $("img.menu").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:256,width:256,opacity:1.0},"fast");
  });
});
```

The img.menu images are placed in a HTML table row.

The images are here:

```
<table border="0" width="700" height="350">
<tr>
<td><img id="about" class="menu" src="img/agenda.png" /></td>
<td><img id="links" class="menu" src="img/laptop.png" /></td>
<td><img id="toolbar" class="menu" src="img/hd.png" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

each one is 256x256 by default

Comment: I think you could achieve the effect you are going for using absolute positioning. You would just need to make sure the z-indexes are set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.menu").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css({'z-index':'9999','position':'absolute'}); 
   $(this).animate({height:300,width:300,opacity:1.0},"fast");
  });

  $("img.menu").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({'z-index':'','position':''}); 
    $(this).animate({height:256,width:256,opacity:1.0},"fast");
  });
});
```

Comment: It makes the images jump from all over the webpage. Thought that it was because I was referencing menu class, but just tried referencing by ID and just the same thing

Comment: try changing z-index according to your need.